# Could not find a result for the specified execution ID

Tags: qlikview

I am using QMC QlikView service for refreshing the documents. When I am calling the **TriggerTask** method of service, it is creating the task execution id successfully. But, with the same task execution id when I am hitting the **GetEDXTaskStatus** method to get the status for first 2-3 times it is saying "Running" but after some time it is throwing the error as:-

> System.Exception: Could not find a result for the specified execution
>   ID "XXX"

Stack Trace:-

> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue before.